# Hevea Error at Non Ascii characters

Tags: html

I tried "Hevea" to convert Xelatex file to html, it worked great with table conversion etc. However my document has lot of characters like (स्वाध्यायनिरताम्)
and I am getting this error.

```
bash-3.2# hevea Bala.tex
./Bala.tex:39: Error while reading LaTeX:
    Non-ascii '?' in input, consider using package inputenc
Adios
```

I tried with `\usepackage{inputenc}` but that did not help. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried supplying the `utf8` option? `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: somehow there was `utf8x` now sure how the x got there. and it worked. thanks for quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried supplying the `utf8` option?

Like so: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`